# AWS get all private ip address in given vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to run an ansible role, for all the ip address in the vpc which are running.
How to get all the ip address of running instance in given vpc

Things: I have tired:

> aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=vpc-id,
>   Values="vpc-******"" --query
>   "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddresses[*]" --output text

This is returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the parameter is *PrivateIpAddress* not `PrivateIpAddresses` as you can see from Json object

```
[
    [
        {
            "Monitoring": {
                "State": "disabled"
            },
            "PublicDnsName": "xxxx",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "State": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "EbsOptimized": false,
            "LaunchTime": "xxx",
            "PublicIpAddress": "xxx",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "xxxxx",
            "ProductCodes": [
            ....
```

so if you run your command as

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=vpc-id, Values="vpc-cda7c6a8"" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" --output text
```

you will have your expected result

Answer (score 0):

it's PrivateIPAddress, not Addresses

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can also add filters:  
`aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --instance-ids --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=instance_name" --output=text`